# Use special symbols in Snakemake parameter section

Tags: python, snakemake

I have created the following snakemake rule:

```
rule cutadapt:
    input:
        input
    output:
        output
    log:
        logs
    params:
        "-a 'A{100}' --nextseq-trim=20 -m 20"
    wrapper:
        "0.50.4/bio/cutadapt/se"
```

and I get the following error message:

> Wildcards in params cannot be determined from output files.

Snakemake realizes `-a 'A{100}'`  as a Wildcard due to the {}. I tried to escape the {} by `-a 'A{{100}}'`  but it produces the same error.

Is there any chance to escape the parameter section in a snakemake rule?

Thanks

Comment: How about escaping using backslash character? ie. `A\{100\}'`?

Comment: Thanks @ManavalanGajapathy. This helps to escape the `{}` for snakemake, but will end up in the final bash call like `cutadapt -a 'A\{100\}' --nextseq-trim=20` resulting in an error. 
What I need is `cutadapt -a 'A{100}' --nextseq-trim=20`

Comment: Makes sense but I am surprised double braces solution isn't working. It might be helpful be to identify if this is a snakemake wrapper issue. To debug, what happens if you try same params in `shell:` command instead of passing it to a `wrapper:`?

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work either. Same problem. Only works when i move the arguments from the params section directly into the shell command. Here, double braces work. But I would like to keep it in the params section to keep it more flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the fix is a bit ugly (see issue https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/584/unable-to-escape-curly-braces-in-params) - I don't know if a better solution has been implemented.

Basically, use a dummy lambda function:

```
lambda wc: "-a 'A{100}' --nextseq-trim=20 -m 20"
```

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake uses the Python formatting, so you can escape curly brace with another curly brace:

```
"-a 'A{{100}}' --nextseq-trim=20 -m 20"
```

Comment: Thanks @Maarten-vd-Sande. As pointed out in the question, I tried double curly braces already. Seems like the quotation marks interfere with the escape {}.

Comment: @pat2402, I didn't properly read your original question, sorry. Does using `-a 'A{{{{100}}}}'` work?

Comment: Tripple curly braces didnt help either. It's still recognized as wildcard. However, the suggestion by @dariober to wrap the parameters in a lambda function helped. Thanks

Comment: @pat2402 I believe 4 braces should work. But the solution of dariober is prettier :)

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande For the historical record: four braces yield the same error